# Style sheets for printing using the @media in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm creating a rails 3.2.x project in which I would like to create a stylesheet for printing. I'm using SASS and the asset pipeline and I've added a file called print.css.scss to my require line in the default loaded sass file.

I've got a class contents and I'm setting the diplay to none for a test. If I remove the @media print block then it works on the screen but still not in the printer.

```
@media print {
   .contents {
      display: none;
    }
 }
```

I've tested printing in Chrome & Firefox, it's like the stylesheet is not getting loaded on print, is there anything else I have to configure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a print manifest file like this and require your print sass file in it like this.

**print.css**

```
/*
 *= require print
 */
```

Then in your layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "print", media: 'print' %>
```

Comment: I had the require line already but not the stylesheet_link_tag for the print media. Thanks

Comment: with only these two steps, I get an error saying -- add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( print.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server -- and even after that, rails includes the `print.css` multiple times, with media="screen". So... doesn't work

Comment: @mmcrae that is probably because you require print in your application manifest as well.

Comment: You probably want to use @import 'print' these days instead of the archaic 'require'